# How to get the value of class properties with Linq query and IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

I have following class.

```
public class User
{
    public User() { }
    public int Id; 
    public string Name; 
    public string Surname; 
    public string PhoneMobil; 
    public string SecondaryPhone; 
    public string Job; 
    public string Sex; 
    public string DepartmentName; 

    public int ID { get{return Id;} set { Id = 111; } }
    public string NAME { get { return Name; } set { Name = "ahsan riaz 1111"; } }
    public string SURNAME { get { return Surname; } set { Surname = "ahsan 1111 riaz"; } }
    public string PHONEMOBIL { get { return PhoneMobil; } set { PhoneMobil = "riaz ahsan"; } }
    public string SECONDARYPHONE { get { return SecondaryPhone; } set { SecondaryPhone = "How are you?"; } }
    public string JOB { get { return Job; } set { Job = "How do you do?"; } }
    public string SEX { get { return Sex; } set { Sex = "What and How do you do?"; } }
    public string DEPARTMENTNAME { get { return DepartmentName; } set { DepartmentName = "ahsan riaz"; } }
}
```

I want to get the value of each property in `Linq` query.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Suggestions<T>(this T user) where T : class
{
    var query = from p in user.GetType().GetProperties()
                select p.GetValue(/* it takes the name of property, i cannot provided name for each property*/);
    return query.AsEnumerable();
}
```

Problem is how to get value of each property by `p.GetValue` in `linq`.

Comment: It seems you have a strange view on how properties work. Your setters don't make sense and many people would consider them outright "wrong".

Comment: Why are you returning IEnumerable<string>, if you have the `Id` field as `int`?

Comment: Are you sure that this code is correct? This would result in stack overflow on first access to any of the properties.

Comment: @Ahsan: In that case, this might be useful: [C# Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 var query = from p in user.GetType().GetProperties()
                    select p.GetValue(user).ToString();
```

The call to `ToString()` is required because you are wanting an enumerable of strings, not an enumerable of objects. However, this does run the risk of a Null Reference error in the case where a property value equals `null`

A safer alternative is this:

```
var query = user.GetType()
                .GetProperties()
                .Select(p => p.GetValue(user))
                .Select(o => Object.ReferenceEquals(o, null) 
                          ? default(string) 
                          : o.ToString()
                       );
```

Comment: compile time error is c=being face. 'p' undeclared identifier.

Comment: First part of answer is perfect. Thanks.

Comment: @Ahsan - I've fixed the 'p' undeclared identifier error - it was a simple syntax error.